# selenium: ManagedPromise::32 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"} message shown before navigating to the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried the following selenium-webdriverJS code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome' }).build();


browser.get('http://localhost:1091/WebTours/sample.html');
var btn = browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('show-coordinates'));
browser.sleep(3000);
var ids = btn.getAttribute("id");
console.log("attributes: " + ids); //expecting to run after above lines.
browser.quit();
```

**Expected:**
navigate to the given URL, find the element and then print the attribute `id` as follows:

```
attributes: show-coordinates
```

**Actual:**
Before navigating to the URL itself, prints `attributes:` with following message:

```
attributes: ManagedPromise::32 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
```

Environment:

```
Windows 7 - 64 bit
selenium-webdriver (installed using `npm install selenium-webdriver`)
ChromeDriver
Chrome
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extract the value from the promise being returned using `then();`

All webdriver commands return a promise as part of the promise manager. This enables you to write

```
driver.findElement(By.css('#searchBar')).clear();
driver.findElement(By.css('#searchBar')).sendKeys('hello');
driver.findElement(By.css('#searchButton')).click();
```

without having to chain them like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.css('#searchBar')).clear().then(function() {
  driver.findElement(By.css('#searchBar')).sendKeys('hello').then(function(){
    driver.findElement(By.css('#searchButton')).click();
  });
})
```

But `getAttribute()`, like many of the Webdriver JS commands, returns a value. In this case you DO need to register a promise callback to extract that value. So your code becomes:

```
browser.get('http://localhost:1091/WebTours/sample.html');
var btn = browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('show-coordinates'));
browser.sleep(3000);
var ids = btn.getAttribute("id").then(function(promiseResult){
  console.log("attribute is: " + promiseResult);
});
browser.quit();
```