# Selenium(javascript) iterate over findElements() and get each of its values

Tags: javascript, selenium

```
var personsWrapper = driver.findElement(By.className('_class1 _class2'));

personsWrapper.findElements(By.tagName('button')).then(function (persons_arr) {
    console.log("length:", persons_arr.length);
    persons_arr.forEach(function (p) {
        var x = p.getAttribute("value");
        console.log(x)
    })
});
```

When I try this I get a ManagedPromise object on the console instead the value of the buttons - why?

Comment: I would say because the value of an input isn't its `value` attribute (that's just the default value), but if these are buttons (I assume you mean `input type=button`), it's unlikely to really matter as the default and current values are very likely to be the same...

Comment: ```<button type="submit" value="Sperren" class="_54k8 _52jh _56bs _3-99 _56bt" data-store="{&quot;onComplete&quot;:&quot;disable&quot;,&quot;pageID&quot;:&quot;113221462151917&quot;,&quot;userID&quot;:&quot;100007881752325&quot;,&quot;userName&quot;:&quot;Mike Mikelson&quot;}" data-sigil="touchable ban_user_from_page_sigil"><span class="_55sr">Sperren</span></button>``` the value of this button is ="Sperren"

Comment: solved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713775/selenium-managedpromise32-promisestatus-pending-message-shown-before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `getAttribute` returns a Promise, thus you need to resolve it first.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var map = webdriver.promise.map;

var elems = driver.findElements(By.css("._class1._class2 button"));

map(elems, e => e.getAttribute("value"))
  .then(function(values) {
    console.log(values);
  });
```

Comment: It's been a looong time since I learned something new about javascript(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)! This works great for looping over array returned by findElements. Thank you! Webdriver docs -> http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html